# MySQL get time duration up to a selected action

Tags: mysql, sql

I am have the following sequence of actions for users and a `DateTime`time stamp of each action.
Below is an example table

```
Actions:
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| session_id | action_name | time                 | 
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 123abcd    | ADD         | 2014-08-27 13:41:02  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 123abcd    | LIKE        | 2014-08-27 13:43:02  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 123abcd    | DELETE      | 2014-08-27 13:45:02  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 123abcd    | EMAIL       | 2014-08-27 13:48:02  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 123abcd    | LIKE        | 2014-08-27 13:52:02  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 546erqr    | ADD         | 2014-08-27 14:02:02  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 546erqr    | EMAIL       | 2014-08-27 14:12:02  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 546erqr    | LIKE        | 2014-08-27 14:14:02  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

As you can see a `user` can go through a `session` performing certain actions.

I am interested in **calculating the time spent before the user sends the email for each session**.

Essentially, I want to do a `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, min(time), max(time))/60` till the `action = EMAIL`. I tried executing it using a `where` clause in the SQL statement, but it didn't work.

For the output, I want something like:

```
+------------+-----------------------+
| session_id | time_till_email_mins  | 
+------------+-----------------------+
| 123abcd    | 7                     |
+------------+-----------------------+
| 546erqr    | 10                    |
+------------+-----------------------+
```

In general, if one were to do computations like this (be it time difference calculations or counting something) *till* a certain action, how does one go about it.

Hope this makes sense. Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to work out - session "123abcd" from "2014-08-27 13:41:02" to "2014-08-27 13:48:02" is not 5.3 minutes!

Comment: `user`? Eh? I can't see that

Comment: @JohnRuddell well, it does say 'mins'

Comment: @EugenRieck: haha! The table was intended for demonstrative purposes as far as data structure is concerned, not for accuracy in values.

@Strawberry:I never mention that there is a field named `user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want this:

```
select   session_id,
         min(time) as first_action_time,
         min(case when action_name = 'EMAIL' then time end) as first_email_time,
         timestampdiff(second,min(time),min(case when action_name = 'EMAIL' then time end)) as diff_in_secs
from     actions
group by session_id
```

This is the difference in seconds between the first action for the session and the first action for the session where the action name is 'EMAIL'.

Comment: Brian, thanks for breaking this down, both in the code and in your brief description. I am still getting the hang of things in SQL, so I am curious to know more about your motivation behind going for the `CASE` statement. Are there other approaches you'd have done?

Comment: The reason for the CASE statement is that you want the first action time where the action_name is "EMAIL". The "where" part of that sentence is a condition. But you can't put that condition into the WHERE clause, otherwise you wouldn't be able to get the first action time for the session overall (at least not in the same query, because the action_name there is not "EMAIL" and so it would be filtered out). That is why you have to provide the condition for the aggregate function within the SELECT list; you do that with a CASE statement (if/then conditions).

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It really helps me understand not only the code, but also the motivation behind it. SQL is an odd thing at times; all logical steps are dispersed between `SELECT` and `WHERE` statements and, at times, I have a hard time having the intuition to do it at the right place. I guess it will come with time and practice? Any suggestions on how to accelerate this?

Comment: @eager_learner313 practice makes perfect, I'd buy a text on sql and use a database to work out some of the examples. If you're focused on MySQL you can get solution stacks like zwamp at http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/ or if you want to try postgresql you can get postgresql portable http://sourceforge.net/projects/postgresqlportable/ , which is similar in syntax and functionality to Oracle and sql server.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select session_id,
       timestampdiff(second, min(case when action_name = 'EMAIL' then action_time end),
                     min(action_time)) / 60
from actions a
group by session_id;
```

Comment: Are there other forms of conditional aggregation that could have solved this? I just heard the term and did a quick search on it, so I am curious about your thoughts. thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Let me try again: are there other types of conditional aggregation that could have gotten us the answer? Some `NULLIF`s or the like? I have used SAS in the past, and I would have introduced a flag and then taken the difference between the two flags (`1`s and `0`s), but it seems adding a new column and a flag and then doing calculations in SQL is difficult? Sorry if this a basic question. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to obtain both values.  Time isn't really a good column name.

```
select session_ID , **(datediff function using first_time and end_time)**

from
(select session_id , min(time) as first_time 
from actions 
group by session)a

inner join

(select session_id, time as end_time
from actions
where action_name = 'email'
group by session_ID) b

on a.session_id = b.session_id
```

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the datediff/time diff functions in MySQL (I put a **placeholder)** in the select line for that), but you should be able to work it from here.